# Conditions on $n\in\mathbb N^+$ for $p\in\mathbb P\implies p^2+2n\notin\mathbb P$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

The condition on $n\in\mathbb N^+$ for 
$$\forall p\in\mathbb P:\, p^2+2n\notin\mathbb P$$
seems to be: 
$$n\equiv 1\pmod 3\wedge 9+2n\notin\mathbb P$$

I would like to see a proof or a counter-example.

Comment: I believe you should edit your post and omit $\forall p\in\Bbb{P}$.

Comment: @Galc127: You are right. Have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,p\in\mathbb P\,$ and $\,p\neq3$, then 
$$p\equiv1\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)\quad\text{or}\quad p\equiv2\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)$$
Square both sides and we have
$$p^2\equiv1\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)$$

First, if $\ \,n\equiv1\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)$, $\ \ $then
$$p^2+2n\equiv1+2\equiv0\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)$$
Thus, $\,p^2+2n\,$ is divisible by $\,3$, which means that $\,p^2+2n\notin\mathbb P$

Besides, if $\,p=3\,$ then for $\,p^2+2n\notin\mathbb P$, it requires $$\,p^2+2n=9+2n\notin\mathbb P$$

Thus, we have proven that if 
$$n\equiv1\ \ ({\rm mod}\ 3)\quad\text{and}\quad9+2n\notin\mathbb P$$
then $\,p\in\mathbb P\ \Rightarrow\ p^2+2n\notin\mathbb P\,$